# Web Elements not appearing in Chromium

Tags: chromium

I have a Pi 4 B, that has a Cortex-A72 ARM processor, running Raspberry PI OS.

[image: difference between chrome and firefox]

On the left we see chromium, on the right firefox ESR.

As you can see, in firefox the site is displaying correctly, with the left menu box displaying all of the sports, but in chromium the same box is just empty.

This isn't a rendering issue because if we look at the HTML we can see the content of these boxes has been replaced by an empty  comment.

Empty in chromium:

[image: empty chromium]

Full in firefox:

[image: full firefox]

What can I do to make Chromium display the website correctly?

Comment: `what is going on?` is not an answerable question because it is too vague ... please ask a clear, answerable question

Comment: `a Pi 4 B, that has a Cortex-A72 ARM processor` ... they all do - `What is going on?` Chrome/Chromium is hot garbage, not sure why it's so popular, every second release breaks something - debugging tip: do you get any errors in the developer console? debugging tip 2: try an earlier version of Chrome/Chromium before they undoubtedly broke some basic function in the latest version which they'll fix in the next version

Comment: @jsotola It is staggeringly obvious I'm asking what is going in relation to HTML elements not appearing in chromium

Comment: @CaptainDucko are you asking about Chromium internals?

Comment: @jsotola All I know is chromium on my pi isn't displaying a website properly. I have idea what could fix this problem. An option in rasperry pi os, a setting on chromium, I don't know.